# Why is logging "slow"?

Tags: postgresql, performance, log

On an empty transient table, inserting a single row took 50ms before changing it to `UNLOGGED`, 1ms afterwards.

Why is this exactly?

If the table structure is necessary, I'll post it, but it's only five columns that normally total 500 bytes per row, a composite primary, and a composite unique.

If possible, can the performance cost be pinpointed to calculation or disk interaction?  If so, what percentage of the cost is due to each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crash-safe logged tables require at least two writes for every transaction:

- A write to the write-ahead log (WAL) recording the data the server intends to write to the table; then
- at some later stage, a write to the real table to apply the change.

The real write can occur after commit, but the WAL write *must* happen before the commit returns (unless `synchronous_commit=off`, which has data safety consequences).

To force that to happen PostgreSQL does an `fsync()`, which flushes the data written to WAL to disk. This operation takes time - on spinning magnetic hard drives it usually takes about one revolution; on an SSD it depends a lot on the amount of other data buffered for writing and on the erase block size etc. Either way, it can take some time.

Unlogged tables do not write to WAL. They just write into shared memory, and as shared memory fills up they write to the real table. No `fsync()` is done because unlogged tables aren't crash-safe.

To reduce the cost of commit flushes on logged tables you should batch your work into bigger transactions. Where the application allows, use asynchronous commit or enable a small commit delay to allow group commit.

Comment: If you mean a laptop HDD, i.e. spinning rust, then the improvement from moving to a *good quality* SSD will be enormous, especially for a commit-heavy workload that does lots of syncs. Do not use a cheap SSD, many of them are unreliable - not crash-safe, risk of data corruption on power loss, etc. Also **don't set `synchronous_commit=off` unless you can accept the resulting data loss window**; see the manual. To learn more see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12206600/398670

Comment: Personally I strongly recommend having your data receivers receive and buffer data then insert in batches, with a retry loop in case the server is unavailable. It makes DB maintenance much easier and will make coping with future load increases simpler.

Comment: See the link I provided above. What you suggest sounds pretty reasonable for the architecture you are describing. I'd still try to batch work where possible.

Comment: "insert tons of values in 1 query". Why not just use a multi-valued insert? Should have no need for a CTE.

Comment: Ah, ok, parent/child. In that case don't worry, it's not a simple insert.